# Perl $#ARGV is always -1

Tags: windows, perl, amazon-web-services, argv

Here is the perl code on AWS Windows 7 VM. In the following code, `e.pl a b` should return `1` in stead of `-1`.

This only happens on AWS VM. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
C:\test>type e.pl
#!c:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
print " \$#ARGV =  $#ARGV\n";

C:\test>e.pl a b
 $#ARGV =  -1
```

------------------- comment ------------- 
Thanks everyone for the help. It is quite complicated because it is part of the http service I was working on.  The problem is within the following 2 lines of codes. The 1st line has interpretor. but it broke the http service. The 2nd line works on my desktop. But it doesn't work on AWS (Amazon Web Service EC2 VM). My trouble shoot found that the 2nd line of code won't pass the $args to the driver.pl. This is very hard to trouble shoot. Thanks everyone for the help!  It is ok if this is not answered.

BTW, I am an experienced perl coder and appreciated everyone's inputs.

#my $cmd = "start C:/strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe c:/$_TAF/driver.pl $args"; <- This broke the http service 
    my $cmd = "start c:/$_TAF/driver.pl $args";                 <- This line won't pass $args to driver.pl

-------- Here are the orig source code ---------

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 {
 package MyWebServer;

 use HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI;
 use base qw(HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI);
 my %dispatch = (
     '/hello' => \&resp_hello,
 );

 sub handle_request {
     my $self = shift;
     my $cgi  = shift;

     my $path = $cgi->path_info();
     my $handler = $dispatch{$path};

     if (ref($handler) eq "CODE") {
            print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"; $handler->($cgi);
     } elsif (-e "${root}${path}")  {   
        print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
        {           #### process taf.cgi 
######################## sub taf_cgi {

my $args = "help";
   $args = $cgi->param("args");  

my $tafRedirectory = $cgi->param("tafRedirectory");
my $refreshRate = 5;
print $cgi->header, $cgi->start_html("$root$path");
print "<pre>";
    {   #my $cmd = "start C:/strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe c:/$_TAF/driver.pl $args";    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    my $cmd = "start c:/$_TAF/driver.pl $args";                     # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if ($^O =~ /win32/i) { ; } elsif ( $^O =~ /linux/i) { $cmd = "/usr/bin/perl /tmp/var/www/cgi-bin/$_TAF/driver.pl $args"; }
    system $cmd;
    }

print<<EOF1;
</pre>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="$refreshRate; url=$tafRedirectory">
EOF1
print $cgi->end_html ;
####################### }
        }
     } 
 }

 sub resp_hello {
     my $cgi  = shift;   # CGI.pm object
     return if !ref $cgi;
 ...... ignored    
 }


 } 

 # start the server on port 8080
 my $httpport = 8080;
 if ($^O =~ /win32/i) {;} elsif ($^O =~ /linux/i) { $httpport = "1234"; }
 my $pid = MyWebServer->new($httpport)->background();
 print "Use 'kill $pid' to stop server.\n";
```

Comment: What do you get if you use an explicit interpreter call.  `perl e.pl a b` ?

Comment: It will print the right answer ARGV = 1

Comment: I'm actually surprised that `e.pl a b` returns anything at all on your Windows 7 VM.  On my system, it just opens up the .pl file in my text editor.  The shebang is a unix construct, so I can't explain why you're even getting `-1` as an answer.  Perhaps someone else would be able to help you with that, but in the mean time I'd just suggest that you specify an interpreter explicitly.

Comment: This is part of another script where add the interpreter will generate wrong answer (I have spend several hours on this. It doens't work in my current code)

Comment: I've shown you how to call a perl script from the command line on windows.  If you want advice about calling it from another script or program, you'll have to provide information about your other script.  Simply saying *"It doesn't work"* leaves no room for giving further advice.

Comment: The shebang is ignored in Windows, although any switches in the shebang will be used. It will *not* use the binary you point to, it will use whatever program your extension is associated with. Did you say that `perl e.pl a b` prints `ARGV = 1`, but just `e.pl a b` gives `ARGV = -1`? That would imply that two different interpreters are used. Try checking what your `*.pl` files are associated with.

Comment: My guess is that you have a broken association with `.pl` files.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have associated `*.pl` files with Perl but have not configured it correctly to pass the command line arguments to the perl interpreter.

For example, searching for "strawberry" through my Windows Registry eventually turns up the file association (under `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Perl_program_file\shell\Execute Perl Program\command` and again under `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Perl_program_file\shell\Execute Perl Program\command`) as

```
"C:\strawberry516\perl\bin\perl.exe" "%1" %*
```

The `%*` at the end is important and I suspect you are missing it -- it stands for all the other command-line arguments (`%1` is the name of your script).

(I am no expert at editing registry values and accept no responsibility for what happens if you try).

Comment: .pl file association was done by Strawberry installation. But this is nice to know.

Comment: Sure it was, but was it done correctly? Or was it overwritten by something else?